# Asp Gridview View changes between edit mode and preview mode

Tags: asp.net, gridview, vb.net-2010

I have an asp gridview control that gets populated via a database(paging allowed). I also enable the user to edit any cell in a row. The gridview control is wrapped in this div tag
  which makes its smaller and take up less screen. It works perfectly until i click the edit button which causes the row selected to be turned into edit mode. When it does this it, highlights the edit row to a color and makes the controls on that row textboxes. I use templates for each column in the gridview. Following;

TemplateField
ItemTemplate
EditTemplate
FooterTemplate

for each column. When the gridview switches to editmode, it renders the grid at basically the default sizing which takes up all the screen and just looks horrible...appears to ignore the div tag. Any ideas on why it switches render size between edit mode and non edit mode? When i cancel the edit action, it renders back to the correct sizing on the initial load of the grid :(

Comment: Can you post your gridview code?

Comment: I copied it straight out of the page, This is a rather large gridview so i need the paging and i also need its size reduced so it doesnt take up the whole page. I'v never had one render size differently between edit and non edit mode so im clueless on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably the edit mode textboxes throwing your grid out of whack.  Your DIV font-size only applies to text span elements, not textboxes.

Try styling your textboxes to reduce their size.  Per link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8680202/how-to-taking-control-of-size-of-gridview-when-its-on-edit-mode-and-its-not):

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCustomer" runat="server">
    ...
    <EditRowStyle CssClass="GridViewEditRow" /> <%-- add this --%>
</asp:GridView>
```

Then add a style for your textboxes:

```
.GridViewEditRow input[type=text] {width:50px;}
```

or, depending on the size of text that may populate those boxes, add the font-size property:

```
.GridViewEditRow input[type=text] {width:70px; font-size: .9em}
```

Comment: Awesome, i'll give this ago today and see if it helps. I'll mark it as an answer or not once i finish testing. Thanks :)

Comment: This worked! I created an external CSS class and linked into my pages. I had to add a few more settings such as width to get it the way i wanted but that looks soooo much better :D

Answer (score 0):

```
<div align="center" style="font-size: smaller;">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:GridView ID="gvCustomer" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="True"
                        ShowFooter="True" BorderColor="Blue" BorderStyle="Double">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                                ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="StandardAcctNo" ShowHeader="true">
                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                    Standard<br />
                                    Account
                                </HeaderTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblStandardAcctNo" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("StandardAcctNo")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtStandardAcctNo" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("StandardAcctNo") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="FtrddlStandardAcctNo" runat="server">
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                                ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="CompanyID" ShowHeader="true">
                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                    Company<br />
                                    ID
                                </HeaderTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblCompanyID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CompanyID")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCompanyID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CompanyID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox Width="50px" ID="ftrCompanyID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                                ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="OrgGroupID" ShowHeader="true">
                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                    OrgGroup<br />
                                    ID
                                </HeaderTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblOrgGroupID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("OrgGroupID")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtOrgGroupID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("OrgGroupID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox Width="75px" ID="ftrOrgGroupID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                                ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="BuyerID" ShowHeader="true">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblBuyerID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BuyerID")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtBuyerID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("BuyerID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox Width="75px" ID="ftrBuyerID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                                ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="SupplierID" ShowHeader="true">
                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                    Supplier<br />
                                    ID
                                </HeaderTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblSupplierID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SupplierID")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSupplierID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SupplierID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox Width="75px" ID="ftrSupplierID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                                ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="CarrierID" ShowHeader="true">
                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                    Carrier<br />
                                    ID
                                </HeaderTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblCarrierID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CarrierID")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCarrierID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CarrierID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox Width="75px" ID="ftrCarrierID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                                ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="TerminalID" ShowHeader="true">
                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                    Terminal<br />
                                    ID
                                </HeaderTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblTerminalID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TruckTermID")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtTerminalID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TruckTermID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox Width="75px" ID="ftrTerminalID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                                ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="CustomerName" ShowHeader="true">
                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                    Customer<br />
                                    Name
                                </HeaderTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblCustomerName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CustomerName")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCustomerName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CustomerName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox Width="100px" ID="ftrCustomerName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                                ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="Tolerance %" ShowHeader="true">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblTolerancePercentage" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Tolerance")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtTolerancePercentage" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Tolerance") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox Width="50px" ID="ftrTolerancePercentage" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                                ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="Credit/Rebill BOL" ShowHeader="true">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblCreditRebillBOL" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CreditRebillBOL")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCreditRebillBOL" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CreditRebillBOL") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox Width="20px" ID="ftrCreditRebillBOL" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnXRefEdit" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Edit"
                                        Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnXRefDelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"
                                        OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to DELETE this entry?');"></asp:LinkButton>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnXRefUpdate" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" CommandName="Update"
                                        ValidationGroup="Update" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to UPDATE this entry?');"
                                        Text="Update"></asp:LinkButton>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnXRefCancel" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel"
                                        Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnXRefAddNew" runat="server" CommandName="AddNew" Text="Add New"
                                        CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="AddNew"></asp:LinkButton>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
< Control style width="" /> between < asp:Boundfield>----< /asp:Boundfield>
```

and it will resolve immediately.